# Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$num_rows

Tags: properties, undefined

i have a problem whit codigniter 3.
i'm in lovalhst using wampserver.
my autoload file

> $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation',
>   'session', 'MY_Router');

the error page [codeigniter 3 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aiwwi.png)

My user model ( **Users_model.php** ) :

```
    class Users_model extends CI_Model{
  public function login_user($username, $password){
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $result = $this->db->get('user');
    if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
      return $result->row();
      $data = array(
      'id'        => $result->id,
      'username'  => $result->username,
      'isadmin' => $result->is_admin,
      'LastOnline'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
  );
  $this->session->set_userdata($data);
  $this->db->where('id',$result->id);
  $this->db->update('user', array('LastOnline'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
    }else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

my users controller ( users.php)

```
    class Users extends CI_Controller{
//function constructe
      public  function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->model('Users_model');
        }
  public function login(){
     $this->load->view('users/login_view');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', array('trim', 'min_length[5]', 'required'));
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', array('trim', 'min_length[5]', 'required'));
     if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
       $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 95%;margin: 0 auto;margin-bottom:5px;"><strong>Error:</strong>', '</div>');
       $data = array(
         'errors' => validation_errors()
       );
       $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
     }else {
       $username = $this->input->post('username');
       $password = $this->input->post('password');
       $validate_user = $this->Users_model->login_user($username,$password);
      if ($validate_user->num_rows > 0) {
        $users_data = $validate_user->row_array();
        $username = $users_data['username'];
        $email = $users_data['email'];
        $level = $users_data['user_level'];
        $SessionData = array(
          'username'  => $username,
          'email'     => $email,
          'level'     => $level,
          'username' => $username,
          'logged_in' => TRUE
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($SessionData);
        if($level === 1){
    redirect('admin/dashboard_view');
} else{
    redirect('users/profile');
}
     }else {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('login_fail', 'faleed');
     }
   }
  }
 }
```